# JSON returns null value of an object, cannot read property of it

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm collecting a JSON response from an external API with Express, and some elements' values are returned to me as null. When I try to use these values (along with others) later, I'm getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of null` error. I tried overwriting it, but it keeps returning null anyway. Can I somehow skip or overwrite this specific parameter value when it's "null"? Here's the part of my code that I have problem with:

```
  var clearbit = require('clearbit')(apikey);
  clearbit.Enrichment.find({email: email, stream: true})
  .then(function (response) {
    var person  = response.person;
    var company = response.company;
    res.render('single-user', { 
        // any of below can be equal to null depending on the email that is being checked
        avatar: person.avatar,
        name: person.name.fullName,
        email: person.email,
        //other properties
     });
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the newly introduced optional chaining (?.) to resolve this. Your code would look like this:

```
var clearbit = require('clearbit')(apikey);
clearbit.Enrichment.find({email: email, stream: true})
.then(function (response) {
  var person  = response.person;
  var company = response.company;
  res.render('single-user', { 
      avatar: person?.avatar,
      name: person?.name?.fullName,
      email: person?.email,
     // Similarly for all properties
   });
})
```

Here is a link for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Hope this helps :)